# Getting Salesforce1 direct links to work?

Tags: salesforce1-app

In what **context** do Salesforce1 direct links work?  They're described on Slide 25 [here](http://www.slideshare.net/developerforce/salesforce1-mobile-tips-tricks-for-admins-33866072).

> How to implement the Direct Email link
>
> com.salesforce.salesforce1://entity/view?entityId=placeDashboardIDhere?entityId=placeYourObjectIDhere

I'm viewing my email with the link on my smart phone in Gmail.  The link, set up as specified above, does not appear as a link in the email message.  If I start the string with "http://" or "https://", I still don't get a link in the message I receive.  I'm using an Android phone.  Do I need to be in the phone's email app or maybe a browser instead of Gmail for this to work?

Has anyone got this direct email link to work?  What application did you use to view/click on the link?

Answer (score 1):

The link should be in the format

```
com.salesforce.salesforce1://entity/view?entityId={!Contact.Id}
```

This should work

Comment: In order for " ... {!Contact.Id}" to resolve to an Id, we have to be in Salesforce, right?  That's my question.  In what context does this work?  The syntax is clear enough, but where am I when I click this?  Salesforce?  An email program? A web browser?  Where?

Comment: You would be in your browser.